Blender Child of constraint has inverted values
I'm trying to perform a retargeting operation on two rigs in Blender 4.0. However, I'm unable to solve it even with the clear inverse/set inverse. The goal is to apply the animation from the "bakedsim" rig to the "rig" rig using the child of system. Can you help me please? Thanks


Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

At least one of your objects has a negative scale:

If you "apply" scale (ctrl+a) to all your objects (or at least to the problematic ones), those weird problems will probably solve.
Since you got a negative scale, there is also a chance that you got flipped normals. Do a face orientation check after fixing the scales.

Edit:
I was able to solve the scale issue by unparenting without keeping transform (this way the scale doesn't cascade to the children).
Then parenting again after fixing the scale.
Things sort of moved, but at least in a less absurd way. The character still looks like a character.
I believe you can retarget now.


If I apply scale to the various objects, strange things happen, and the two models start to invert. I also tried applying rotation since I noticed that the root_trans object has a 90° rotation on the X axis and 180° on the Y axis.

For example, if I apply scale to the auskel object, everything flips upside down.

Well.... unfortunately you created everything based on an inverted object... I'm not sure there is a fix that doesn't involve flipping things back to where they should be.

If you're lucky, you can create a new object to replace the inverted one, and try to parent everything else to the new object using "keep transform".

@AlexCroft, or you can try to "unparent", keep transform, apply scale to the problematic objects and reparent.

I'm not very experienced with Blender. I tried to remove the parent and apply the transforms, but I keep getting strange results. Maybe i'm missing something. Could you please help me using the attached file?

@AlexCroft, I solved the scale issue (see update), although I'm not that experienced with armatures. It seems you will need some manual fixing, but the behavior will probably be steady.

thank you daniel. sorry for the late response. i've opened your blend file, now the "bakedsim" model is rotated, both models have to stay straight. i tried to rotate it (, but then it is difficult to retarget. Is there a way to rotate "baked sim" in order to have the same exact position of both the rigs?

Maybe if you put the model as a child in an empty and rotate the emtpy, not sure it will work.

Ok, I did it and it seems to work. However, in the retargeting process using the child of, some movements match, others don't. For example, the legs cross, but the arms don't follow the animation correctly. Could it be due to the T-pose?
This is the file:

